# Securely serving up data via API to app and the residing site

Tags: php, api

I'm not quite sure if an API is the way to go with this, so a little background.

I have been building up a back end which has a very useful set of data and tools for someone to run a site. The front end also uses the same data to show to customers, as one would expect. A mobile app could probably be added in the near future to enable changes to be made to the site, via the app. But the back end can potentially go onto any website like a standard script (ie. it is not centrally stored nor does any data go back and forth between the client and us).

So I thought that the best way around this would be to make an API for the site. Naturally for an app to access the API, it would need a key to authenticate with the API (which the end user can set via their back end). However, I would like the back and front ends to use the API to access the same data so nothing needs to be written twice.

I'm sure it is clear that APIs are a new thing to me, which they are. But, I am trying to improve and adapt my coding to be more efficient.

I thought perhaps that the API could perhaps do some checks from the location of the query to see if it were local request (back/front end) or via an app (which uses a key + user authentication). So how would one go about ensuring that the back and front end could securely access the API, while no one can access it via spoofing. I imagine the checks could be on the lines of the requesting URL, but I am worried that this could be spoofed or other things (that could be checked) could be spoofed. What is the best way to allow local access? Is there anything that can't be spoofed?

I know I could write in a key into the code, but since the code is distributed, I don't want this access key to be public - nor do I want to manually change the key for each site - and nor do I really want the end user to enter some random letters and numbers during setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a public/private key. Your front/back end's, mobile versions, or even 3rd party developers will then use the their keys to authenticate each other.

Comment: Sounds like you are saying to hardcode the key for the front/back end into the PHP code? But surely then all that means is one person finds the key within the code, then they can access every API from every install? How to ensure that the request is only coming from the site that it should be coming from?

Comment: I suggest you read this Wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography